# how to disable a select button after onclick on a value of another select button

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and CSS.

I am doing a simple application.My requirement is ,I have two select button ,when I will click on first select button value then corresponding value will come in the second select button.

I have 5 values in the first select button and  I have corresponding value only for first two values.But I don't have any corresponding value in the second select button for other 3 values.

That means when I will click on first value of the first select button then the corresponding value will come in the second select button and same will be for second value,but when I will click on any one among (3,4,5) then in that case I should disable the second select button ,as I don't have any corresponding value for last values.

**Coding**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#select1").change(function() { 
          if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
           $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());} 
        var id = $(this).val();
        var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
         $('#select2').html(options);
      });
   });
</script>

 <div class="pageCol1">
    <div class="panel">
    <div class="templateTitle">Request for Items</div>  
    <table class="grid" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="gridAlternateRow">
            <td><b>Item to be Request</b></td>
            <td>
            <select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="change();">
                    <option value="1">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="2">Stationaries</option>
                    <option value="3">Computer Accessories</option>
                    <option value="4">Bottle</option>
                    <option value="5">Chair</option>
                    <option value="6">Office File</option>
                    <option value="7">Phone Facility</option>
                    <option value="8">Other Facilities</option> 
            </select>
          </td></tr>
          <tr><td>
          <b>Category</b>
          </td> 
          <td>  
            <select name="select2" id="select2" >
              <option value="1">--Select--</option>
                <option value="2">Note Books</option>
                <option value="2">Books</option>
                <option value="2">Pen</option>
                <option value="2">Pencil</option>
                <option value="2">Eraser</option>
                <option value="2">Drawing sheets</option>
                <option value="2">Others</option>
                <option value="3">Laptop</option>
                <option value="3">PC</option>
                <option value="3">CPU</option>
                <option value="3">Monitor</option>
                <option value="3">Mouse</option>
                <option value="3">Keyboard</option>
                <option value="3">Mouse Pad</option>
                <option value="3">Hard Disk</option>
                <option value="3">Pendrive</option>
                <option value="3">CD/DVD Writer</option>
                <option value="3">RAM</option>
                <option value="3">Mother Board</option>
                <option value="3">SMPS</option>
                <option value="3">Network Cables</option>
                <option value="3">Connectors</option>
                <option value="7">Land Line</option>
                <option value="7">BlackBerry </option>
                <option value="7">Other</option>
              </select> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gridAlternateRow">
        <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <b>Description</b>
            </td>           
            <td>
            <div class="row">
                    <textarea cols="5" rows="3" style="width:650px;"></textarea>
                </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
        <tr class="gridAlternateRow">
        <td><b>Reason</b></td>
            <td>
            <textarea cols="5" rows="3" style="width:650px;"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b>File Upload</b></td>
            <td>
              <div class="row">
                   <input type="file" name="somename" size="chars"> 
                 </div>
                </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    <div class="btnSection">
        <a class="btnPrimary" href="" title="Button">SUBMIT</a>
        <a class="btnPrimary" href="" title="Button">RESET</a>
       </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  .gridAlternateRow td {
        background:#f3f6f8;
                      }
             .row {
               clear: both;
               overflow: hidden;
               padding: 4px 0;
                }
```

Can any one tell me how to solve this ?

Comment: Where's the related code? I can see just HTML markup. And your question shouldn't be tagged with `CSS`.

Comment: I can see the code now, thanks.

Comment: Where is the function `change()` you're using here: `onchange="change();"`?

Comment: check my third line code

Comment: You misunderstood the jQuery `.change()` event handler. You're handling it in your code, so you don't need to use `onchange="change();"` in your markup.

Comment: with the help of this change i am retrieving the value for second select  button

Comment: The `options` in your second `select` have all the same `value`. Is this right?

Comment: why got negative...it is not question ?can anyone tell me ?

Comment: can you provide some link through which i may get the concept

Comment: I've posted an answer. I hope it has enough explanation to make you go on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There we go...

If you're planning to use the value returned by the select #2, you should have its options values unique.

Just for testing purposes and to suggest you a solution:

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="0">--Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
    <!-- The data-value here is to link both selects. -->
    <option value="0" data-value="0" selected>--Please select</option>
    <option value="1" data-value="1">Option 1/1</option>
    <option value="2" data-value="1">Option 1/2</option>
    <option value="3" data-value="1">Option 1/3</option>
    <option value="4" data-value="2">Option 2/1</option>
    <option value="5" data-value="2">Option 2/2</option>
    <option value="6" data-value="3">Option 3/1</option>
    <option value="7" data-value="3">Option 3/2</option>
</select>
```

...

```
$(function () {
    // Keep the select #2 default options.
    var currentOptions = $("#select2 > option").clone();

    // When the select #1 changes.
    // Note that this is replacing the onchange you've 
    // placed in the markup before.
    $("#select1").on("change", function () {
        // Restore the default options for the select #2.
        $("#select2").empty().append(currentOptions);

        var selectedValue = $(this).val();

        // Nothing selected, just return.
        if (selectedValue == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Filter the select #2 valid options by matching
        // their data-value with the select #1 value.
        // Also include the first option (-- Please select).
        var validOptions = $("#select2 > option").filter(function () {
            var thisVal = $(this).data("value");

            return (thisVal == 0 || thisVal == selectedValue);
        });

        // Clean up the select #2 and add the valid options.
        $("#select2").empty().append(validOptions);

        // If the select #2 contains just one option, disable it.
        $("#select2").prop("disabled", $("#select2").find("option").length == 1);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/sy12trb7/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following `jquery` code

Jquery

```
var $drop1 = $("#drop1");
var $drop2 = $("#drop2");
$drop1.change(function () {

    var value = $(this).val();
    if ($("#drop2 option[value = '" + value + "']").length) {
        $drop2.prop("disabled", false);
        $drop2.val(value);
    } else $drop2.prop("disabled", true);
});
```

html

```
<select id="drop1">
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<select id="drop2">
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/u891bahd/2/)

Answer (score -1):

```
**JSFIDDLE**
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mhr3T/)**

```
Here is the **sample demo jquery select button disable** ,you can try to follow this you will get solution and good understanding 


var myId;

$('select').change(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    myId = $this.attr('id');
    myVal = $this.val();
    if (myId == 'dropDown1') {
        $('select').prop('disabled',false);
        if (myVal == 1) {
            $('#dropDown4').prop('disabled', true);
        }else if (myVal == 2) {
            $('#dropDown3').prop('disabled', true);
        }else if (myVal == 3) {
            $('#dropDown2').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Include javascript file at the top ot the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Download jquery.min.js to your folder

Put css inside `<style></style>`

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I had got result by making the changes that i wrote

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#select1").change(function() { 
          if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
           $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());} 

        var id = $(this).val();
       // alert(id);
        var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');

      if(options.val() == undefined){

            $('#select2').prop("disabled",true);
        }else{

            $('#select2').prop("disabled",false);
         $('#select2').html(options);
        }
      });
   });

</script>

 <div class="pageCol1">
    <div class="panel">
    <div class="templateTitle">Request for Items</div>  
    <table class="grid" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="gridAlternateRow">
            <td><b>Item to be Request</b></td>
            <td>
            <select name="select1" id="select1">
                    <option value="1">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="2">Stationaries</option>
                    <option value="3">Computer Accessories</option>
                    <option value="4">Bottle</option>
                    <option value="5">Chair</option>
                    <option value="6">Office File</option>
                    <option value="7">Phone Facility</option>
                    <option value="8">Other Facilities</option> 
            </select>
          </td></tr>
          <tr><td>
          <b>Category</b>
          </td> 
          <td>  
            <select name="select2" id="select2" >
              <option value="1">--Select--</option>
                <option value="2">Note Books</option>
                <option value="2">Books</option>
                <option value="2">Pen</option>
                <option value="2">Pencil</option>
                <option value="2">Eraser</option>
                <option value="2">Drawing sheets</option>
                <option value="2">Others</option>
                <option value="3">Laptop</option>
                <option value="3">PC</option>
                <option value="3">CPU</option>
                <option value="3">Monitor</option>
                <option value="3">Mouse</option>
                <option value="3">Keyboard</option>
                <option value="3">Mouse Pad</option>
                <option value="3">Hard Disk</option>
                <option value="3">Pendrive</option>
                <option value="3">CD/DVD Writer</option>
                <option value="3">RAM</option>
                <option value="3">Mother Board</option>
                <option value="3">SMPS</option>
                <option value="3">Network Cables</option>
                <option value="3">Connectors</option>
                <option value="7">Land Line</option>
                <option value="7">BlackBerry </option>
                <option value="7">Other</option>
              </select> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gridAlternateRow">
        <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <b>Description</b>
            </td>           
            <td>
            <div class="row">
                    <textarea cols="5" rows="3" style="width:650px;"></textarea>
                </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
        <tr class="gridAlternateRow">
        <td><b>Reason</b></td>
            <td>
            <textarea cols="5" rows="3" style="width:650px;"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><b>File Upload</b></td>
            <td>
              <div class="row">
                   <input type="file" name="somename" size="chars"> 
                 </div>
                </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    <div class="btnSection">
        <a class="btnPrimary" href="" title="Button">SUBMIT</a>
        <a class="btnPrimary" href="" title="Button">RESET</a>
       </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want to achieve? [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/s149rqfp/1/)

I have added this to your JS:

```
 var disable_id = [ 3,4,5 ]; 
 $('#select2').html(options); //This line is in your original code
  if ( jQuery.inArray(id-1, disable_id) != -1 ) {
      $("#select2").attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
      $("#select2").attr('disabled', false);
  }
```